# MongoDb Extension for Yii 2 throwing error of extension not installed

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I'm trying to install Yii2 mongo extension, I have already installed the mongo php driver and it showing in phpinfo. Please refer the screenshot for error. I have tried with both mongo and mongodb drivers, none are working.
I have tried the composer command

> composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0

from
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php
its still the same output.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a second php.ini for CLI version - probably mongodb is not added there (or just commented out). `php --ini` in console should help you find it. Fix configuration, restart apache and it should be fine.

Comment: I have command you have mentioned, it only show one configuration file only, the same in which I have added the extension.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in the [installation guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)?

Comment: Or maybe try this `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0" --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Yes I have followed the steps mentioned. I have 64bit OS and wamp.
The command you gave run properly, but still was getting the same here for yii2 extension, the command for Yii is `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb`

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb`, mongodb is working with basic command mentioned in php site.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo driver is deprecated, in place of that mongodb drivers are added for newer version of PHP. Try installing Mongodb driver.

Steps for installation

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Comment: I have tried both mongo and mongodb drivers, the result is same for both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Xamp, I had issue with wamp and mongodb in windows.
refer this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwiTzYnW4-jPAhUfTY8KHalTAlIQFgguMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegeekstuff.com%2F2015%2F10%2Fphp-mongodb-for-xampp&usg=AFQjCNF1xQNah_S6V_dfMpfKQSJvISfTAg&sig2=WbYpPKZnQPztGHp9cZdT8g&cad=rja) for procedure.